# python has an error walking through the dictionary of the list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbwWv.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9S3H.png)
I print the type of row,however I still don't solve this problem,please help me,thank you!
I wonder why this is a problem? And how to solve it.

Comment: Please post your code and output as text.

Comment: Are your sure all your dictionaries have a key `"Microbe"`? If one row happens to have less than 3 items, its dictionary will not have `"Microbe"` key

Comment: In particular, the (only) interesting output would be the last `row` that it prints before raising the error

Comment: For debugging purposes you should catch the `KeyError` exception and then, print that row.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your hitting an object in your list, without 'microbe' data/or not readable data.

The fastest way to solve this is adding exceptions to each variable.

That way, your programm wont break, when a single data-entry is not readable.
I usually fill the variable with a placeholder ("no xxx data") so i could still work with filled variables.
In your example:

```
for row in data:
try:
    microbe_name = row['Microbe']
except:
    microbe_name = "no microbe_name data"

try:
    drug_name = row['Name']
except:
    drug_name = "no drug_name data"

try:
    molecular_form = row['Molecular Form']
except:
    molecular_form = "no molecular_form data"

try:
    target = row['Target']
except:
    target = "no target data"

try:
    pubmed_id = row['PubMed ID']
except:
    pubmed_id = "no pubmed_id data"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing some of the rows in data does not have they key `microbe`, to cross check run

```
for row in data:
    if 'microbe' not in row:
        print(row['Name'])
```